# What are the JointStateHandle units?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-control, ros-kinetic, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ros_control c++ interface and JointStateHandle to update the motor feedback values. My question is about the units used in the parameters of the following line:

```
hardware_interface::JointStateHandle state_handle_1(right_joint, &pos_[0], &vel_[0], &eff_[0]);
```

I suppose that vel_ has the unit [rad/s]. But what unit does pos_ have? Is it [m] or [rad]?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328531/what-are-the-jointstatehandle-units?/) by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2019-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This message type can describe both linear and rotary joints, so the units used will depend on the type of joint.

If it's a rotary joint the units are radians, radians per second, and Netwton metres.

If it's a linear joint the units are metres, metres per second, and Netwtons.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2019-07-15**:
Yes it helps. I tested it with my rotatory joint and it is rad/s, rad and Nm.